# Automatically change header name in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two equations z=x+a*n and ze=x+b*n, where a and b are constant. Here x and n varies from 0 to 10 with 1 interval. I have to write all these on to a dat file with first column with all values of x, then next column with values of z with n=0, next column with values of ze with n=0, next column value of z with n=1, next column value of ze with n=1 and so on. And also I have to put a header. The code goes like this:

```
clear all;clc;
format long;
a=4;
b=2;
mat1=[];
mat2=[];
for n=0:10
    i=0;
    for x=0:1:10
        i=i+1;
         z(i,:)= x+a*n;
         ze(i,:)= x+b*n;
    end
    mat1=[mat1,z, ze];
end
x1(:,1)=0:1:10;
dat1=[x1,mat1];
outputfilename1=('mat1.dat');
fileidentifier1=fopen(outputfilename1,'w+');
fprintf(fileidentifier1,'x\t z0\t ze0\t z1\t ze1\t z2\t ze2\t z3\t ze3\t z4\t ze4\t z5\t ze5\t z6\t ze6\t z7\t ze7\t z8\t ze8\t z9\t ze9\t z10\t ze10\t \r');
fprintf(fileidentifier1,'%7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f \n',dat1');
fclose(fileidentifier1);
```

Problem starts from putting header.

What I used to do is that I used to give the command for each of these thing manually: i.e. ‘x’, for first column, ‘z0’ for second column corresponding to n=0, ‘ze0’ corresponding to ze with n=0, 'z1' for z where n=1, 'ze1' for ze where n=1 and so on. Similarly, for format specification (ie %7.10f). As you can see that it will be a hectic of a task if that ‘n’ varies up to 100 or more. Also if you want to change the value of n from 10 to 9, the output file will still show the correct values, but the way it is arranged will become haywire (you can try for yourself). Is there any way to write do this automatically?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3):

You can create all of the `z*\t` components using `sprintf` with an array of numbers as input. You can then concatenate this with the leading `'x\t '` and the trailing `\r`

```
fprintf(['x\t ', sprintf('z%d\\t ', 0:10), '\r'])
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it was indeed very helpful. But there is a small hitch here. You yourself can see it if you changed the value of n from 10 to any other, say n=5. In this case, though the z will print up to z5, the output file will be printed in strange manner.
I have in my mind a way out for this: 
if instead of writing 
`fprintf(fileidentifier1,'%7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f \n',dat1')`;
like this, is it possible to write something like **n times %7.10f**. Then this will be very much helpful…

Comment: Suppose that I have `for n=0:10

i=0;
for x=0:1:10
i=i+1;z(i,:)= x+a*n;
end
mat1=[mat1,z ze];
end`
where b is any number. If I want to write x in first column, then z0, z1,.. ze0,ze1 ..., how can i modify the program? What matlab is doing by default is that it prints z0,ze0,z1,ze1 etc with this command. I tried with this command as I need headers for this: fprintf(fileidentifier1,['x\t ', sprintf('z%d\\t',0:10,'ze%d\\t',0:10), '\r']);

**to be continued 1/2**

Comment: **continued 2/2**
fprintf(fileidentifier1,'%7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f %7.10f \n',dat1');
I think you may now see that why I asked that question in the previous comment..

Comment: Please add `ze(i,:)= x+b*n;` after `z(i,:)= x+a*n` in **continued 1/2**

Comment: @sreerajt I can't tell what you mean because it's hard to read it in the comments. Please update your question showing the expected input/output

Comment: I have updated the question @Suever. Please go through it if possible...

Answer (score 0):

So your issue is dynamically creating the string

```
'x\t z0\t z1\t z2\t z3\t z4\t z5\t z6\t z7\t z8\t z9\t z10\t \r'
```

You can simply do this in a loop:

```
str = 'x\t';
for zNum = 0:10
    str = [str, ' z', num2str(zNum), '\t'];
end
str = [str, ' \r'];
```

Output:

```
str = 'x\t z0\t z1\t z2\t z3\t z4\t z5\t z6\t z7\t z8\t z9\t z10\t \r'
```

Now in your code you can use it in the relevant lines

```
fprintf(fileidentifier1, str);
```

Comment: @Wolfie...thanks a lot. However, there is a small trouble here. I have mentioned that on Suever answer. Please see it...